# Matriz em python

Tags: python-3.x, matriz

Estou construindo uma matriz em python, mas não consigo fazer a impressão correta. 
Alguém poderia me ajudar. Segue o código:

```
 linhas = 4

 entrada = input()
 valor = entrada.split()
 matriz = []
 while (entrada != ''):
     for i in range(linhas):
           linha = []
          for j in range(len(valor)):
                valor[j] = int(valor[j])
                linha.append(valor[j])

   matriz.append(linha)
   entrada = input()
   print(*matriz, sep='\n')
```

Quando digito:

```
           1 2 3 4 

           5 5 6 7
```

A impressão é:

```
           [1, 2, 3, 4] 

           [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou atualizar a variável `valor` dentro do loop:

```
linhas = 4

entrada = input()
valor = entrada.split()
matriz = []
while (entrada != ''):
    for i in range(linhas):
        linha = []
        for j in range(len(valor)):
            valor[j] = int(valor[j])
            linha.append(valor[j])
    matriz.append(linha)
    entrada = input()
    valor = entrada.split()

print(*matriz, sep='\n')
```

Pois, como você está utilizando a variável `valor` para criar as linhas da matriz é preciso atualiza-la depois de receber o *input* do usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Quando estamos trabalhando com matrizes devemos saber o número de `linhas` e também o número de `colunas`.

Se a sua intenção é montar uma matriz você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo abaixo. Observe que, neste algoritmo, utilizei o laço de repetição `for` em vez do `while`.

```
import numpy as np

m = int(input('Digite o número de linhas: '))
n = int(input('Digite o número de colunas: '))

matrizTemp = list()
for c in range(1, m + 1):
    linha = list()
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        while True:
            try:
                valor = int(input(f'Digite o {i}º elemento de {c}ª linha: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros!\033[m')
        linha.append(valor)
    matrizTemp.append(linha)

# Exibindo a matriz e suas dimensões.
matriz = np.array(matrizTemp)
print(f'\033[32mA matriz gerada é:\n{matriz}')
```

Observe que quando executamos este algoritmo nos é solicitado o número de `linhas` e, em seguida, o número de `colunas`.

Depois de ter inserido o número de linhas e de colunas, devemos digitar cada um dos elementos que desejamos inserir na matriz. Depois de ter inserido todos os possíveis elementos da matriz e pressionar `enter`, o algoritmo montará e exibira a referida matriz.

Answer (score -2):

```
import random

lista = []
linha = []
nc = int(input('Quantas colunas? '))
nl = int(input('Quantas linhas? '))

for i in range(nl):
    for i in range(nc):
        randomNum = random.randrange(-5,5,1)
        linha.append(randomNum)
    lista.append(linha)
    linha = []
for k in lista:
    print (k)
```